# My internal hard disk is 0 byte and a flashing question mark

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, hardware

I have been striving to bring my laptop to life,
however, I am seeing a flashing question mark on my MacbookPro screen.

I tried disk utility and it is just showing me Media and it is 0 byte.

I ran DiskWarrior and it gave following error:
An unexpected error occurred while communicating with this hard drives built in S.M.A.R.T. diagnostics, error -536870210, 28260C-

Comment: What brand and type of hard disk is in your system? Part#?

Comment: It is what I got from Apple only. Segate momentum 5400 rpm 250 GB (I don't know exact name.)

Answer (score 1):

I installed a new hard disk. Problem was my old harddisk died because of shakes.